# Learning Java: How to make a short alias for System.out.println()

Tags: java

I would like to make an alias of or an extended version of `System.out.println()` for printing my variables of various types. How does one pass an argument with unknown type/class to a method?

```
public static void p(VariableType... args) {
    System.out.println(args[0]);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If you use eclipse, typing "syso" and hitting CTRL+Space is sufficient.

Comment: Design suggestion: if your variables are all related, they should be grouped in some class (`MyVars`).  Then you would only have to override `toString()` of that class and call `System.out.println(myVars);`.

Comment: cularis, I use IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: toto, I just wanted smth shorter. It is a small program for CLI and I got annoyed by retyping the standard method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you want lots of lines in the output, you could do.

```
public static <PrintableToString> void p(PrintableToString... args) {
    for(PrintableToString pts: args)
        System.out.print(pts);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Usualy, generic class Name consists of one letter :)

Comment: True, But there is no way to specifiy that the object should have a printable/sensible toString() method. ;)

Comment: Is there a way to somehow not have to import the class each time I want to use it? Because sysout is just too long but it has the benefit I don't need to import it, I'd like to just have log

Comment: @Ced in my ide I type `sout` + `<tab>` Your IDE should have templates.  If your IDE is not writing 40% of the Java code for your, you are working to hard/not using your IDE enough.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `Object`.

```
public static void p(Object... args) {
  System.out.println(args[0]);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: +1 here, and implement `toString()` in each class of the variables you're going to print. How does that _not work_ ? Care to explain a bit more ?

Comment: Ivan, if your question is for me, then when I was trying with Object there was another mistake which brought me to the wrong conclusion. So I was expecting this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558008/learning-java-how-to-make-a-short-alias-for-system-out-println/6558046#6558046

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
public static <T> void p(T... args)
{
    System.out.println(args[0]);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is elegant, but it restrains that all arguments have to be of the same type.

Comment: @Marcelo: No it doesn't (try it if you don't believe me)

Comment: @Marcelo T can be Object i.e (essentially) anything

Answer (score 3):

Others have answered your question.

I'd just like to point out that your `p` method is a bad style and (probably) a bad idea:

1. The method name `p` doesn't tell anyone what it does.
2. Writing to standard output is usually a bad idea.  The exception is when the application is designed to be run as a command line utility.
3. Even if it is right to write to standard output, doing it that way is limiting your ability to reuse your code.  A better approach is to make the stream a parameter; e.g.

   ```
   public void outputFoo(Foo foo, PrintStream ps) {
       ps.println("Foo's bar is " + foo.bar);
       // ...
   }
   ```
4. If the `p` method is going to be used for trace prints, then using your `p` wrapper rather than `System.err.println` will hide the traceprints from style checkers like PMD.  You might think this is a good thing, but in fact it is a bad thing, because now PMD won't remind you to remove the trace prints before you put your code into production / ship it to customers.

Comment: Thanks for your advices! My program is a very simple one, just to learn how to parse RSS-feed and post to a server. I wanted a simple shortcut for printing out.

Comment: Thanks again! This is my first Java program, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use Object, because Object is the type of all Java variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple solution, which works for all my use cases:

```
public static final void print(Object x) { System.out.println(x); }
```